# Java & MySQL - Unique Key not working?

Tags: java, mysql

I'm using the MySQL Workbench, and assigned one of my columns as a Unique Key.
When I check the MySQL table, it still enters duplicates for "users_name"
I'm still new to MySQL/Java, so I'm sure I'm just making a silly mistake.

```
System.out.print("Name: ");
String name = sc.nextLine();
System.out.print("Password: ");
String pass = sc.nextLine();

String SQL = String.format("INSERT INTO users (users_name, users_password) values('" + name + "','" + pass + "')");
PreparedStatement stmt = (PreparedStatement) connection.prepareStatement(SQL);
stmt.executeUpdate(SQL);
```

MySQL Table Definition:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`users` (
`users_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`users_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
`users_password` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`users_id`) ,
UNIQUE INDEX `users_id_UNIQUE` (`users_id` ASC) ,
UNIQUE INDEX `users_name_UNIQUE` (`users_name` ASC) )
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Comment: The important info would be your table definition

Comment: What do you mean by that? Sorry.

Comment: @JonathonCharlesLoch: It means please show the sql statment that created your table. something like: `create table users(id int...`

Comment: @juergend: Post it as an answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

Not really an answer, but very helpful advice:

This is how you should use your `PreparedStatement`:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO users (users_name, users_password) values (?, ?);";
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
stmt.setString(1, name);
stmt.setString(2, pass);
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

To answer your actual question, we need to see the table definition.

Comment: +1 definitely don't String-concat in the values of your PreparedStatement as OP has in the code snippet above.

Comment: Well, I made a new table, with the same Primary Keys, Uniques, Auto Increments, etc. And now it works.
Guess something didn't work last time.